# Based on the proportion of the number of days before, during and after the Spring Festival, calculate the festival effect

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

Suppose we have monthly data as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
    'date': ['2008-1-31', '2008-2-29', '2008-3-31', '2008-4-30', '2008-5-31', '2008-6-30', '2008-7-31',
             '2008-8-31', '2008-9-30', '2008-10-31', '2008-11-30', '2008-12-31', '2009-1-31NaN',
             '2009-2-28', '2009-3-31', '2009-4-30', '2009-5-31', '2009-6-30', '2009-7-31', '2009-8-31',
             '2009-9-30', '2009-10-31', '2009-11-30', '2009-12-31'],
    'value': [390.93, 327.62, 365.53, 366.88, 380.44, 379.33, 380.83, 372.10, 392.45, 406.16, 398.09, 428.61,
              np.nan, 366.46, 411.08, 415.77, 436.33, 429.12, 438.05, 448.02, 473.18, 466.84, 465.20, 516.17]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], errors='coerce')

          date value
0 2008-1-31 390.93
1 2008-2-29 327.62
2 2008-3-31 365.53
3 2008-4-30 366.88
4 2008-5-31 380.44
5 2008-6-30 379.33
6 2008-7-31 380.83
7 2008-8-31 372.10
8 2008-9-30 392.45
9 2008-10-31 406.16
10 2008-11-30 398.09
11 2008-12-31 428.61
12 2009-1-31NaN
13 2009-2-28 366.46
14 2009-3-31 411.08
15 2009-4-30 415.77
16 2009-5-31 436.33
17 2009-6-30 429.12
18 2009-7-31 438.05
19 2009-8-31 448.02
20 2009-9-30 473.18
21 2009-10-31 466.84
22 2009-11-30 465.20
23 2009-12-31 516.17
```

I hope to generate an new festival effect column based on the annual Spring Festival, 20 days before the festival, 7 days during the festival, and 10 days after the festival. The coefficients for each date range are 3, 1, and 2.5, respectively. Taking 2008 as an example, the detailed calculation process is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

coef1 = 3
coef2 = 1
coef3 = 2.5

spring_festival_date = ['2008-02-07', '2009-01-26', '2010-02-14']

# v1 is the proportion of the number of days before the festival in January, and then multiplied by the first coefficient
date1 = pd.to_datetime(spring_festival_date[0]) - datetime.timedelta(days=20)
diff1 = date1 - pd.to_datetime('2008-01-31')
v1 = abs(diff1. days) / 31 * coef1

# The part of February in the 20 days before the festival accounts for the number of days in February, and then multiplied by the first coefficient
v2_1 = 7/29 * coef1

# The part of February in the 7 days in the section accounts for the number of days in February, and then multiplied by the second coefficient
date2 = pd.to_datetime(spring_festival_date[0]) + datetime.timedelta(days=7)
diff2 = date2 - pd.to_datetime(spring_festival_date[0])
v2_2 = abs(diff2. days) / 29 * coef2

# The part of February in the 10 days after the festival accounts for the number of days in February, and then multiplied by the third coefficient
date3 = pd.to_datetime(spring_festival_date[0]) + datetime.timedelta(days=17)
diff3 = date3 - date2
v2_3 = abs(diff3. days) / 29 * coef3

# February Spring Festival impact factor is v2
v2 = v2_1 + v2_2 + v2_3
```

The question now is assuming that I have multiple years of data, how to calculate through the function, and generate a column of `sprint_festival_effect` in a effcient method?

The expected result:

```
          date   value  sprint_festival_effect
0    2008-1-31  390.93                1.258065 # (31-18)/31 *3
1    2008-2-29  327.62                1.827586 # 7/29 *3 +7/29*1 +10/29*2.5
2    2008-3-31  365.53                     NaN
3    2008-4-30  366.88                     NaN
4    2008-5-31  380.44                     NaN
5    2008-6-30  379.33                     NaN
6    2008-7-31  380.83                     NaN
7    2008-8-31  372.10                     NaN
8    2008-9-30  392.45                     NaN
9   2008-10-31  406.16                     NaN
10  2008-11-30  398.09                     NaN
11  2008-12-31  428.61                     NaN
12   2009-1-31     NaN                2.096774  # 20/31 * 3 +5/31*1
13   2009-2-28  366.46                0.964286  # 2/28*1 +10/28*2.5
14   2009-3-31  411.08                     NaN
15   2009-4-30  415.77                     NaN
16   2009-5-31  436.33                     NaN
17   2009-6-30  429.12                     NaN
18   2009-7-31  438.05                     NaN
19   2009-8-31  448.02                     NaN
20   2009-9-30  473.18                     NaN
21  2009-10-31  466.84                     NaN
22  2009-11-30  465.20                     NaN
23  2009-12-31  516.17                     NaN
```

**Updates:**

```
def calculate_spring_festival_impact(spring_festival_date, coef1, coef2, coef3):
     spring_festival_date = pd.to_datetime(spring_festival_date)
     year = spring_festival_date.year
     month = spring_festival_date.month

     days_in_month = pd.Timestamp(year, month, 1).days_in_month

     # Calculate the ratio of the 20 days before the Spring Festival to the number of days in the month
     date1 = spring_festival_date - datetime.timedelta(days=20)
     diff1 = date1 - pd.Timestamp(year, month, 1)
     v1 = abs(diff1.days) / days_in_month * coef1

     # Calculate the ratio of 7 days in the Spring Festival to the number of days in the month
     date2 = spring_festival_date + datetime.timedelta(days=7)
     diff2 = date2 - spring_festival_date
     v2 = abs(diff2.days) / days_in_month * coef2

     # Calculate the ratio of 10 days after the Spring Festival to the number of days in the month
     date3 = spring_festival_date + datetime.timedelta(days=17)
     diff3 = date3 - date2
     v3 = abs(diff3.days) / days_in_month * coef3

     return v1, v2, v3

# Example usage
spring_festival_date = '2008-02-07'
coef1 = 3
coef2 = 1
coef3 = 2.5

v1, v2, v3 = calculate_spring_festival_impact(spring_festival_date, coef1, coef2, coef3)
print(v1, v2, v3)
```

Out:

```
1.4482758620689655 0.2413793103448276 0.8620689655172414
```

Comment: Is it possible t make this a bit more general than your specific example? Unsure about the broader usefulness if it's just about your spring festival data. Are you asking for help with a specific part of writing the function?

Comment: You may consider it as festival like Easter, which means it doesn't fall on a fixed date each year.

Comment: ah bon it looks like you have solved your own answer? I just ran the code and it seems to work okay. Could you create an answer and move your solution to there! Thank you! :-)

Comment: I'm not sure it's correct answer since it's different from `sprint_festival_effect` column. I generated by using cursor.

Comment: can you elaborate, or add the data discrepancies to the question?